# Как сверстать эту таблицу

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть данная картинка-пример, не знаю как сверстать так, чтобы были линии разделяющие картинки.

Нужна просто идея
[image: Верстка]

Comment: Уже видел вопрос  идентичный, с этим же самым скрином...  А что именно не получается?

Comment: Мне написал то, как сделать такое расположение картинок, но мне нужно сверстать линии разделяющие их

Comment: можно  просто псевдо-элементами...  Можно бордерами...  Можно отдельными элементами... Можно В канвасе наривовать... можно в SVG нарисовать...  Вожможностей куча

Comment: покажите вашу вёрстку без разделяющих линий - мы поможем продвинуться дальше. без кода получается совсем голословное обсуждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, здесь реализация зависит от HTML-разметки, а HTML разметка зависит от того, где это будет использоваться и что будет с адаптивом. Вам видимо без разницы какая будет разметка и где это вообще будет использоваться, а вопрос адаптивности тем более не заботит. В таком случае, возьмите мой вариант.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 7vw;
}

.col {
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1.5vw;
  width: 25%;
}

.col:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/4F84DB/FFFFFF" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```